# AutoResetEvent Set called after timeout

Tags: c#, autoresetevent, event-wait-handle

From MSDN "If there are no waiting threads, the wait handle remains signaled until a thread attempts to wait on it, or until its `Reset` method is called."

```
EventWaitHandle MyWaitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false);
```

Thread # 1:

```
public void Method1()
{
  //do something
  //wait for the signal or timeout
  MyWaitHandle.WaitOne(10000);
  //do something else on receiving signal or after timeout
}
```

Thread # 2:

```
//this would be called when there is a response from the external app
public void Method2()
{
  //do something
  //send the signal to waiting thread
  MyWaitHandle.Set();
}
```

In my application Thread # 1 is submitting a request to external app and waiting for a signal or timeout. If a response is received from the external app Thread # 2 sets the wait handle. This `set` can be called even after the timeout. My questions are

1) It is highly possible that `Method2` can be called after the timeout resulting in setting the signal. Does that mean whenever there is a request to Thread # 1 in the future, the `WaitOne(10000)` has no effect and will be released immediately?

2) Is there anyway for me to not call `set` in `Method2` in case of timeout? Would that cause any problems to the Thread # 1?

Comment: Why would you not want to set the event even after a timeout? Does Method2 not signal that something is ready for Method1? Perhaps if you explain what you're trying to accomplish...

Comment: `Method2()` would not know if it is being called after timeout. There lies the issue. Well, I can monitor the time and set a `bool` variable to find out if it is timedout. But Can I call the `Set()` based on a `bool` value. If I don't call would it leave any open handles or anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just make sure the wait handle is always reset before waiting on it?

```
public void Method1()
{
  // Reset the wait handle I'll be using...
  MyWaitHandle.Reset();

  //do something
  //wait for the signal or timeout
  MyWaitHandle.WaitOne(10000);
  //do something else on receiving signal or after timeout
}
```